# How to call SOAP web service from in SENCHA TOUCH 2?

Tags: soap, sencha-touch-2

- How to call  SOAP web service from in SENCHA TOUCH 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been successful using other libraries along side with sencha touch. you include them in your project, and will have access to them in your controllers. http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Sencha Touch does not provide a proxy for that: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?243660-Consume-a-SOAP-web-service-in-Sencha-Touch-2

If you are savvy, try porting [this](http://www.sencha.com/blog/taking-a-look-at-the-new-sencha-soap-data-proxy).